# Load Webpage when an Item is clicked in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

i have a ListView that simly shows items on it.
I want to load a webpage e.g; google.com , when i click an item of the list view.
how can i do this? plz explain with a code sample.
i m new to android.

here is my list view code:

```
 package com.androidListActivity;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyList extends ListActivity 
{   
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //        setContentView(R.layout.main);

String[] names = new String[]
        {
            "One",
            "Two"
        };
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowlayout, names));

}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
}
}
```

Plz edit this for example.
Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for editing my question Ramakrishna:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
    Intent in = new Intent(this,WebViewPage.class);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

WebViewPage.java

```
public class WebViewPage extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webviewpage);
            WebView wbView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
            wbView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
            wbView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
   }
}
```

webviewpage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<WebView
android:id="@+id/WebView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally add permission in Manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".WebViewPage" />


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Sensible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://androidbook.blogspot.com/");  
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);  
    startActivity(launchBrowser);  
}
```

Add Internet permission to manifest and it should work :)

good luck,
Arkde

Answer (score 0):

Use This code

```
list_Id.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    list_Id.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            WebView webView = new WebView(v.getContext());
                            String[] urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bookmark_urls);
                            webView.loadUrl(urls[position]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Then Create a file name `string-array.xml` inside `values`, put all web addresses you need:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="bookmark_urls">
        <item>http://www.google.com</item>
        <item>http://www.facebook.com/</item>
        <item>http://www.android.com/</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```